# Sheaf cohomology free module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, projective-schemes

Let $X \rightarrow$ Spec$A$ be a scheme over a ring $A$. I know that if $X$ is a projective scheme over $A$, and $A$ is Noetherian. $H^p(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is afinitely generated A-module for all $p \geq 0$.

If $A$ is not a field, $H^p(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ not necesarilly has to be a free $A$-module, but I can not find an example of this.

Thus, does anyone know any projective $A$-scheme $X$, with $A$ Noetherian, such that $H^p(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is not a free module for some $p \geq 1$?

If, because of some result that I do not know, $H^p(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ happens to be free always in this case, I would like to ask this question in general without assuming that $A$ is Noetherian or $X$ is projective: does anyone know an $A$-scheme $X$ such that $H^p(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is not a free $A$ module for some $p \geq 1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m \subset A$, and take any scheme $X$ which is projective over $k = A / \mathfrak m$. Then $H^p(X, \mathcal O_X)$ will be a $k$-vector space, which is certainly not a free $A$-module as long as $A \neq k$ and $H^p(X, \mathcal O_X) \neq 0$. Note that $X$ is projective over $A$ because $\operatorname{Spec} k \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is projective.